# How to execute multiples procedures from nodejs and node-firebird?

Tags: node.js, firebird, firebird2.5, node-firebird

I'm using Firebird 2.5 and node-firebird 0.8.6. I have to run SQL files with multiple stored procedures but I always got errors like the ones below

> Error: Dynamic SQL Error, SQL error code = -104, Token unknown - line 1, column 5, term
>       at doCallback (/home/somasys/Downloads/testefb/node_modules/node-firebird/lib/index.js:1234:18)
>       at /home/somasys/Downloads/testefb/node_modules/node-firebird/lib/index.js:2929:21
>       at /home/somasys/Downloads/testefb/node_modules/node-firebird/lib/messages.js:151:25
>       at search (/home/somasys/Downloads/testefb/node_modules/node-firebird/lib/messages.js:117:13)
>       at /home/somasys/Downloads/testefb/node_modules/node-firebird/lib/messages.js:54:21
>       at FSReqCallback.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:477:5)

Here it's some parts of my SQL file:

```
set term ^;
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE PRC_CALCULATRIBUTA() 
   BEGIN 
      ...
   END^
set term ;^
commit work;

set term ^;
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE PRC_CORRIGEENCERR() 
   BEGIN 
      ...
   END^
set term ;^
commit work;
```

I've already tried to remove these `set term` and `commit work` and ran it (SQL script) inside a

```
EXECUTE BLOCK AS 
BEGIN
  ...
END
```

but even so I got the same errors like the one described above. Is there any instruction or statement to put inside my SQL script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird's statement API can only execute individual statements. In addition, the `SET TERM` statement is not part of the Firebird SQL syntax. It is only a client-side feature in ISQL and other Firebird tools to determine when a statement is done. See also [firebird procedural query throwing "token unknown" error at "SET TERM #;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774655/firebird-procedural-query-throwing-token-unknown-error-at-set-term).

You will need to:

- split up your SQL script in individual statements,
- remove the `SET TERM` statements
- remove any statement terminators outside the procedure bodies, and
- execute the statements individually.

I would also suggest to not execute `commit work`, but instead use the transaction control options from node-firebird. I'm not sure if executing `commit work` will work in node-firebird, but some drivers will break because you just closed a transaction on them without using their transaction API.

In other words, you will need to execute:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE PRC_CALCULATRIBUTA() 
   BEGIN 
      ...
   END
```

optionally execute the commit, or commit explicitly using the node-firebird API, and then

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE PRC_CORRIGEENCERR() 
   BEGIN 
      ...
   END
```

etc.

You cannot use `execute block` for this, because `execute block` doesn't support execution of DDL. There are workarounds to that limitation (using `execute statement`), but it is generally not a good use of `execute block`.

As an aside, committing between creating stored procedures is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks in advance. Your answer was very enlightening. I'll take these steps and rerun my sql files. One more time thanks.

Comment: @FelipePaz perhaps you can implement script executive on top of `node-firebird` and then commit it to the library. It would require a limited FSM-based SQL semi-parser, that can split the script into independent statements. You can look into Delphi Unified Interbase library for example implementation.